# What fields are accessible when I use the Facebook login on my site?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=facebook+login+api+what+fields+are+available) which appears to have a lot of information about the social graph api.  Not sure if that is related?

Basically If I implement a facebook login for my site, what fields will I have available for use.

Here is a partial list:

```
[id] => 10206477717245530
[email] => foo@yahoo.com
[first_name] => foo
[gender] => male
[last_name] => foo
[link] => foo
[locale] => en_US
[name] => foo
[timezone] => 6
[updated_time] => 2015-08-02T06:56:59+0000
[verified] => 1
```

Where can I get a complete list, for example I would assume that the user picture is available.

These fields I will eventually populate to a mysql database using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

to get an idea what is available. You'll need the appropriate permissions to request the fields,
see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5

Also, concerning `picture`, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: If a user simply clicks, login with facebook, what permissions will I have ?

Comment: If you don't specify any permission for login, it will have `public_profile`

Comment: but basically I have to ask the user if I want more than just public_profile permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the Facebook API's user info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

To get a user's profile picture simple populate this path with a Facebook ID.

`https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_id.'/picture?type=large`

The type can be sent with as a string (small, large) or you can replace it  with ?width=250&height=250.

Comment: do you know if there is a default width/height for the image that is returned, if you do not specify anything.

Comment: It will display the small 50x50 square thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

`public_profile` is the default scope *all* Graph API requests for a user, and contains the following fields:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-public_profile

Comment: I find it strange, that there is no field for picture, but according to another answer this can be obtained from the `id`

Comment: Because `picture` isn’t a field, but rather an edge. It is an endpoint unto itself.